# Date Input Focus/Edit

Tags: html, date, kaios

When focusing on input with type `date` the simulator brings up the Date edit dialog, but am unable to edit the value. Seem as if keystrokes are still being reported to the current DOM and not the date dialog?

```
<input type="date" id="dateinput" name="dateinput" />
```

How can I manually trigger the edit dialog and block it from showing on focus?

Sample app can be found **[here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoUmGPGezONi2x015XM-pw5H20f1?e=b56L6E)**.

Comment: You question needs more elaboration, some working example may helps to understand your question

Comment: Here is a sample app with the date input scenario scenario. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoUmGPGezONi2x015XM-pw5H20f1?e=b56L6E